# how to get unique rows with some conditions using pandas or excel

Tags: excel, pandas, data-analysis

my table is like this

```
Now
Id , age , gender , IsDiabetes, Is Obese, IsHeart
 1    23    Female     Yes         No      Yes 
 1    23    Female     Yes         Yes      Yes 
 2    60    Male       Yes         No       No 
 3    70    Female     No          No       Yes
 3    70    Female     No          Yes       Yes
```

My desired outcome is if there is Yes put it insted of No
I do not need unuseful duplication

```
Desired 
Id , age , gender , IsDiabetes, Is Obese, IsHeart
 1    23    Female     Yes         Yes      Yes 
 2    60    Male       Yes         No       No 
 3    70    Female     No          Yes       Yes
```

I tried

```
data1 =df.groupby('ID').agg(list)
```

but this is not the best solution for me. the results not working  when i opened the excel file.

Comment: I was going to try and add an Excel solution (the original question only tagged python/pandas) but never mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can aggregate `max` because lexicographically is `Yes` greater like `No`:

```
data1 = df.groupby(['Id','age','gender'], as_index=False).max()
print (data1)
   Id  age  gender IsDiabetes IsObese IsHeart
0   1   23  Female        Yes     Yes     Yes
1   2   60    Male        Yes      No      No
2   3   70  Female         No     Yes     Yes
```